# Scala - Given a dynamic list of sub-objects, create one object that contains the sub-objects

Tags: scala

Given classes like this:

```
case class Foobar(
  subObjectA: SubObjectA,
  subObjectB: SubObjectB,
  subObjectC: SubObjectC,
)

trait SubObject

case class SubObjectA(
  foo: Int
) extends SubObject

case class SubObjectB(
  bar: String
) extends SubObject

case class SubObjectC(
  baz: String
) extends SubObject
```

and a list of SubObjects like this:

```
val list = [SubObjectA(1), SubObjectC("one")]
```

How can I generate one class Foobar from the list of SubObjects? The list is dynamic, and so I wont know which objects are in the list, but they will all be a subtype of SubObject. SubObjects will also never have more than one of the same type in the list. But not all SubObjects will always be in the list.

Would reduceLeft/foldLeft be the answer? I'm not sure how I would set the fields subObjectA and subObjectC as the respective objects from the list

Edit: Basically I am trying to generate a class Foobar with subObjectA set to the SubObjectA(1) in the list, and subObjectC set to the SubObjectC("one") in the list

Edit2: another detail I missed was the list can be in any order, and there will be ~20 SubObjects. Is there not a way to iterate through the list, match on the type of SubObject, and then use an empty Foobar class, and use copy to iteratively copy Foobar.copy(subObjectA = subObjectA)?

Comment: What should be the result of `b1, a1`, `a1, b1, a2`, and `a1, a2, b1, b2`?

Comment: I think I was unclear with the question, I have updated so it makes more sense. My apologies! If you are asking how the elements of the list will be, they will be unique, and so there will never be duplicates of any SubObject type

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the problem correctly one of possible solutions could be:

```
val list: List[SubObject] = ...

val (optA, optB, optC) =
  list.foldLeft[(Option[SubObjectA], Option[SubObjectB], Option[SubObjectC])](
    (None, None, None)
  ) {
    // last override wins, if you need first wins replace _ with None
    case ((_, optB, optC), a: SubObjectA) => (Some(a), optB, optC)
    case ((optA, _, optC), b: SubObjectB) => (optA, Some(b), optC)
    case ((optA, optB, _), c: SubObjectC) => (optA, optB, Some(c))
    case other                            => other
  }

val fooOpt: Option[Foobar] = for {
  a <- optA
  b <- optB
  c <- optC
} yield Foobar(a, b, c)
```

It makes only pass iteration over the list. If you wanted more readable solution which could potentially get over list trice, you could do:

```
val fooOpt: Option[Foobar] = for {
  a <- list.collectFirst { case a: SubObjectA => a }
  b <- list.collectFirst { case b: SubObjectB => b }
  c <- list.collectFirst { case c: SubObjectC => c }
} yield Foobar(a, b, c)
```

You could also try tail recursive function:

```
@scala.annotation.tailrec
def resolveFoo(
  list: List[SubObject],
  optA: Option[SubOptionA] = None,
  optB: Option[SubOptionB] = None,
  optC: Option[SubOptionC] = None,
): Option[Foobar] = (list, optA, optB, optC) match {
  case (_, Some(a), Some(b), Some(c))     => Some(Foobar(a, b, c))
  case (Nil, _, _, _)                     => None
  case ((a: SubOptionA) :: tail, _, _, _) => resolveFoo(tail, Some(a), optB, optC)
  case ((b: SubOptionB) :: tail, _, _, _) => resolveFoo(tail, optA, Some(b), optC)
  case ((c: SubOptionC) :: tail, _, _, _) => resolveFoo(tail, optA, optB, Some(c))
  case (_ :: tail, _, _, _)               => resolveFoo(tail, optA, optB, optC)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, another detail I missed was the list can be in any order, and there will be ~20 SubObjects. Is there not a way to iterate through the list, match on the type of SubObject, and then use an empty Foobar class, and use copy to iteratively copy Foobar.copy(subObjectA = subObjectA)?

Comment: But that's exactly what this code does: it goes through whole list and finds matching types. If it finds match, it replaces `None` with `Some`, and if in the end there are 3 some, then it uses their content to call constructor. If you need to call 20 parameters, the you would need 20 options - or `collectFirst` combined with `mapN` from Cats. Not the best performance but it would work. Doing things with `.copy` sounds as if you wanted to use Java Bean rather than case class - it has this nasty property that you might end up with incompletely initialized object.